# Non-canonical page in sitemap

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, canonical-link, rel

I added a link tag in the header of some pages like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://wazedomain.com/page" />
```

But I still get the error for pages like:

```
"https://wazedomain.com/page/disclaimer"
"https://wazedomain.com/page/privacy"
```

I read on Google that if I add the rel="canonical" tag on my link, it will work but it didn't.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What error? From where? What outcome are you looking for?

Comment: I created an audit in ahrefs for my website wazedomain.com and after audit, I got an error that tells me that 12 pages do not have a canonical page in sitemap. And as a result google search console does not index 18 pages from site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still getting errors likely because you added the wrong canonicals.

In the page `https://wazedomain.com/page/disclaimer`, the canonical points to `https://wazedomain.com/`, which is your homepage. That would mean the canon, or original, or main, of the disclaimer page is your homepage. That makes no sense.